# aks-engine custom image for node

Tags: azure, kubernetes

On the aks-engine github there is an example for a custom image for a node as follows:

```
"agentPoolProfiles": [
  {
    "name": "agentpool1",
    "count": 3,
    "imageReference": {
      "name": "stretch",
      "resourceGroup": "debian"
    },
    "vmSize": "Standard_D2_v2",
    "availabilityProfile": "AvailabilitySet"
  }
]
```

When I use this in my aks-engine generated ARM it can't find the resource group because I have not created it and not uploaded an a debian VHD as an Image in Azure.

Is there a way of using pre-made images on Azure instead of having to upload our own?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/issues/721#issuecomment-420304966 seems related, but the work on this issue is still in progress.

Comment: Any more update for the question? Is that you want?

Comment: If you just want to run a couple of commands on your node, creating a `DaemonSet` which executes those commands using `nsenter` might already be sufficient. https://medium.com/@patnaikshekhar/initialize-your-aks-nodes-with-daemonsets-679fa81fd20e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean to create a custom image without upload your own VHD file in Azure when you say using the pre-made images. Then the answer is yes. You can create the image from the base images that Azure provided in the marketplace through the [Packer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/build-image-with-packer) tool or [Capture the image from the Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image).

As you see in the aks-engine custom image, you need to create the custom image in the resource group first, and then use both resource group name and image to quote the custom image to create the agent pool. The description in [agentPoolProfiles of aks-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/clusterdefinitions.md#agentpoolprofiles).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS) to create a managed AKS cluster, you won't be able to use the custom image or the gke-engine.

[See the comment from Microsoft's employee on Aug 3, 2018](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/12629):

> Currently, AKS does not support deploying custom VM image as agent
>   nodes. You can use ACS-Engine. Here is the link to open source version
>   of ACS-Engine: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine

Comment: I don't think you're right. The custom image does not support in AKS currently, but support in aks-engine. It's the next version of acs-engine. See the [example](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/examples/custom-image.json) that custom image in aks-engine.

Comment: @CharlesXu i think op is using aks to create a managed cluster and because of that, might not be able to use custom images. Have updated the answer to reflect the same.